# Mootools - Destroy a node within an object not in the DOM

Tags: javascript, mootools

Mootool's destroy method doesn't appear to work if the element is not in the DOM:

```
var statics = $('statics').clone(true, true);

statics.destroy('.prototype');

statics.inject($('main'));
```

In this example, I attempt to strip out all elements with the class "prototype" from the statics object. It fails.

Any advice?

EDIT:

By comparison, I could achieve this with jQuery using a similar pattern:

```
var statics = $('#statics').clone();

statics.remove('.prototype');

$('#main').html(statics);
```

Which is probably why I am trying to do it the same way with Mootools

Answer (score 2):

mootools destroy function is not getting any parameter - it works only on the target element and his childrens - so what you are looking for is this:

```
var statics = $('statics').clone(true, true);

statics.getElements('.prototype').destroy();

statics.inject($('main'));
```